# Trying to understand the internal implementation & the reason why we need an ErrorBoundary in React as a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

It started with a few basic questions.

- Why can't I wrap my components in a try/catch block and do what ErrorBoundary does?
- Why do we need a special kind of component to do the job?

This led me to try and figure out how React implements and handles ErrorBoundary internally. I wanted to figure out how React catches the error, handles it, and call the `getDerivedStateFromError` static method defined in the ErrorBoundary class component.

After going down the rabbit hole, I figured that there's a `renderRootSync` function that has the first try/catch block in the rendering pipeline. Looks like this.

```js
  do {
    try {
      workLoopSync();
      break;
    } catch (thrownValue) {
      handleError(root, thrownValue);
    }
  } while (true);
```

This `handleError` function eventually does a bunch of processing and calls [`throwException`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c08d8b8041a1fa2eba423cdb0398dfbc6402a5bc/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberThrow.new.js#L311) function. This function is again responsible for figuring out the type of component and what to do with a failed render depending of various types of component. Also gather some metrics.

I was surprised though when I didn't see a final `throw` somewhere in this function. That means the original error (the `value`) param in `throwException` function isn't being propagated.

This takes away the ability for the consumer to wrap components in a try/catch of their own and handle error scenarios.

Instead, the `throwException` function, for a class component, finds the static `getDerivedStateFromError` method and executes it.

Is this a design choice to not throw the original error? Is this done to give a declarative, component based API to the consumers so they don't have to do the try/catch handling of their own?